Replacing regular Sora Shifters with dropbar shifters
I have normal shifters & brakes, both Sora. Brakes are hydraulic disc brakes. Can I replace them with dropbar shifters, i.e. are there Sora dropbar shifters with a cable for the gears and hydraulic for the brakes?
Edit: turns out the breaks are not Sora but some different range, as Sora doesn’t exist in hydraulic.



when you say "normal shifters", do you mean shifters designed for flat bars?

Sora certainly used to be a drop bar range, so the question is slightly puzzling. I have an idea that shimano released some flat bar levers under the sora name, which might have been to work with road bike parts, but I'm not sure.

@ChrisH I think I recall some Sora flat bar shifters at one point as well. But I'm also not sure.

Indeed -SORA is available in dropbar and flatbar shifters.  https://bike.shimano.com/en-NZ/product/component/sora-3500/SL-3500.html  and  https://bike.shimano.com/en-NZ/product/component/sora-r3000.html

See edits in original post

There are no Sora hydraulic disc brakes, but some bikes are sold with cable actuated hydraulic calipers (like the TRP Hy/RD). If this case, the lever is technically a cable brake lever. So if it is your case, you can use regular Sora drop bar shifters. Note however that a flat bar Sora with cable actuated hydraulic calipers would be a very strange choice from the manufacturer, given the availability and price of the MT200/UR300 (entry level Shimano hydraulic disc brakes, that are very good and much cheaper than the Hy/RD alone).
For drop bar shifters, the entry level with hydraulic disc brakes is otherwise Tiagra (or GRX400 for gravel), but that would require to replace the whole groupset (because there are no 9-speed road groupsets with hydraulic disc brakes).
If the bike has true hydraulic disc brakes, but non-Sora and you want after the upgrade "true hydraulic" and drop bar, you'll also need to replace the whole groupset.
EDIT: the answer doesn’t change with the addition of the photos, but gets nuanced: the callipers could potentially be kept (or replaced by post mount callipers, as road groupsets are usually sold with flat mount callipers(buying a bundle is usually cheaper than buying components separately)

Normally, this would be the correct answer. However, in this case I suspect that the OP has flat bar Sora shifters, hydraulic brakes (flat bar fevers), and actually wishes to do a flat-to-drop bar conversion.

@PaulH It's how I understood the question: even in Sora flat bar, there is no hydraulic option. I've seen the combo MT201/UR300 on some road-focused hybrids, but that would go against the what the OP has written, as the MT201 are technically in the Altus range, not Sora. The non-Sora hydraulic is covered in the last sentence (and would require to replace the groupset - technically the calipers could be kept, but it's often cheaper to buy complete groupsets rather than the components separately).

Ahh yes. I misread your answer. Apologies.

That’s right, I want to do what Paul H suspected. It’s a flat bar with true hydraulic brakes. Can I not use a 10sp shifter with hydraulic brake and one of the jtek bits for it work with the 9sp cassette? If so what shifter would I need? Grx or tiagra?

I suspected from the start that this was about Sora shifters and separate brake levers without obvious range branding. That's common on flat bar components (e.g. on my hardtail) and would lead to a bit of confusion.

@ChrisH it’s also what I suspected, and instead of waiting for an answer of the OP (that I didn’t expect to come back to complete the inaccuracy of the question), I wrote an answer that covers all cases.

@Rеnаud, and I'm glad you did, because otherwise I would have had to and I didn't have all the information in my head. I thought I'd already given you a +1, but apparently not; I've fixed that now

Thanks guys for the comprehensive answers which corrected all my inaccuracies. How about if I get a shiftmate 2 and a 10sp tiagra shifter? I wouldn’t need to replace the whole group set, right?

@mi_in Shiftmate addresses a mismatch between the shifter and the derailleur, but the number of speeds between the shifter and the cassette will always need to match. Shiftmates are also in the same price range as 10-speed derailleurs, so not sure there's a real saving there.

@mi_in a much easier alternative is to fit "inner bar ends": it gives you an additional hand position that is closer to the hoods on drop bars (and you can still access gears and brakes).

@mi_in Which brake model is there? Is it supposed to be compatible with road hydraulic brake levers?
